# workaround for 16mb limit on variant datatype in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a snowflake stored procedure to execute select query and return resultset inside json array.It errors out due to 16mb limit.Is there any workaround for the snowflake stored procedure to return the result set of the select query without breaking 16 mb limit?

Comment: is there a work around for the 16mb object.... no... If your single object has more that 16mb of json, I suggest it is not AN json object.... if it an array etc, then just return many rows...

Comment: its a json array

Answer (score 2):

You may want to [return the resultset as a table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets.html#returning-a-resultset-as-a-table) rather than as a JSON array. If this is not feasible, then you may want to use a [cursor to retrieve one array row](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/cursors.html#using-a-cursor-to-fetch-data) at a time.

Answer (score 1):

16MB limit is related to the internal representation of the large objects, so there is no workaround for now. In future, I expect that Snowflake will support larger objects.

I do not know why you need to execute a SELECT inside the stored procedure, but maybe Snowflake Scripting can help you to return the JSON array as multiple rows:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/return.html#returning-a-value

Comment: Is there any limit to the number of rows returned using snowflake scripting